# With ag-grid, how can I set the value of a cell whenever an adjacent cell's cellValueChanged event has fired?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Whenever the user edits a cell in a particular column, I want to copy their value to an adjacent cell and remove the value from the cell they edited. From the `event` object, I can get the `newValue` from the cell that was edited, but I don't know to get a reference to a different cell and set its value.

```
gridColumnDefinitions = [
   {
      headerName: 'Column A',
      field: 'columnA',
      editable: true,
      onCellValueChanged: (event) => {
          var newValue = event.newValue;

          //Move new value to columnB and set this value to "".
          //How??
      },
    },
    {
      headerName: 'Column B',
      field: 'columnB',
      editable: false,
    }
]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define `onCellValueChanged` on columnA something like this -

```
  onCellValueChanged : (params) => {
      if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
        params.data.columnB = params.newValue; // assign to new adjacent column
        params.data.columnA = ""; // change the underlying data 
        params.api.refreshCells({columns : ["columnA","columnB"]}) ;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Works, but I had to use this.agGrid.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs) and this.form.updateValueAndValidity() instead of refreshCells